Excel Macro That Sends Files As An Attachment In Outlook No Longer Works With Windows 11 Outlook
I'm a teacher and not a developer.  Copied this code from another program that involves stores and modified it to send grade reports.  Was a programmer once but not a vba programmer.  I now get a message that Outlook is not open even when it is.  Any advice?
Option Explicit

Sub SendEmailTest()
SendEmailWithPDF (True)
End Sub

Sub SendEmailStores()
SendEmailWithPDF (False)
End Sub

Sub SendEmailWithPDF(bTest As Boolean)
Dim wsM As Worksheet
Dim wsL As Worksheet
Dim wsR As Worksheet
Dim wsS As Worksheet
Dim rngL As Range
Dim rngSN As Range
Dim rngTN As Range
Dim rngPath As Range
Dim c As Range
Dim lSend As Long
Dim lSent As Long
Dim lCount As Long
Dim lTest As Long
Dim lOff As Long

Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim strSavePath As String
Dim strPathTest As String
Dim strPDFName As String
Dim strSendTo As String
Dim strSubj As String
Dim strBody As String
Dim strMsg As String
Dim strConf As String

On Error GoTo errHandler
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

strMsg = "Could not set variables"
Set wsM = wksMenu
Set wsS = wksSet
Set wsL = wksList
Set wsR = wksRpt
Set rngL = wsL.Range("StoreNums")
Set rngSN = wsR.Range("rngSN")
Set rngTN = wsS.Range("rngTN")
Set rngPath = wsS.Range("rngPath")
'test email address
strSendTo = wsS.Range("rngSendTo").Value

lCount = rngL.Cells.Count
'#columns offset for email address
lOff = 3

If bTest = True Then
   strConf = "TEST Emails: "
   lTest = rngTN.Value
   If lTest > 0 Then
      lCount = lTest
   End If
Else
   strConf = "STORE Emails: "
End If

strConf = strConf & lCount _
      & " emails will be sent"

If bTest = True Then
  If strSendTo = "" Then
    MsgBox "Enter a test email address" _
     & vbCrLf _
     & "and try again."
    GoSettings
    GoTo exitHandler
  Else
    strConf = strConf & vbCrLf _
      & "to " & strSendTo
  End If
End If

strConf = strConf & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
strConf = strConf & "Please confirm: " _
  & vbCrLf & _
  "Do you want to send the emails?"

lSend = MsgBox(strConf, _
  vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Send Emails")

If lSend = vbYes Then
  strSubj = wsS.Range("rngSubj").Value
  strBody = wsS.Range("rngBody").Value
  strSavePath = rngPath.Value
  
  strMsg = "Could not test Outlook"
    
  On Error Resume Next
  Set OutApp = _
   GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
  On Error GoTo errHandler

  If OutApp Is Nothing Then
      MsgBox "Outlook is not open. " _
       & vbCrLf _
       & "Open Outlook and try again"
      GoTo exitHandler
  End If
  
  strMsg = "Could not set path" _
     & " for PDF save folder"
  If Right(strSavePath, 1) <> "\" Then
      strSavePath = strSavePath & "\"
  End If
  
  If DoesPathExist(strSavePath) Then
    'continue code below,
    ' using strSavePath
  Else
    MsgBox "The Save folder, " _
      & strSavePath _
      & vbCrLf & "does not exist." _
      & vbCrLf & _
        "Files could not be created." _
      & vbCrLf & _
        "Please select valid folder."
      wsS.Activate
      rngPath.Activate
    GoTo exitHandler
  End If

  strMsg = "Could not start mail process"
  For Each c In rngL
     rngSN = c.Value
     
     strMsg = "Could not create PDF for " _
         & c.Value
     strPDFName = "Algebra Test Results_" _
         & c.Value & ".pdf"
     If bTest = False Then
        strSendTo = c.Offset(0, lOff).Value
     End If
      wsR.ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:=strSavePath _
          & strPDFName, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=False
      
      Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
  
     strMsg = "Could not start mail for " _
           & c.Value
      On Error Resume Next
      With OutMail
          .To = strSendTo
          .CC = ""
          .BCC = ""
          .Subject = strSubj
          .Body = strBody
          .Attachments.Add _
             strSavePath & strPDFName
          .Send
      End With
      On Error GoTo 0
     lSent = lSent + 1
     If lSent >= lCount Then Exit For
  Next c
  
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  wsM.Activate
  
  MsgBox "Emails have been sent"
  
End If

exitHandler:
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   Application.DisplayAlerts = True
   Set OutMail = Nothing
   Set OutApp = Nothing
   
   Set wsM = Nothing
   Set wsS = Nothing
   Set wsL = Nothing
   Set wsR = Nothing
   Set rngL = Nothing
   Set rngSN = Nothing
   Set rngPath = Nothing
   
   Exit Sub
   
errHandler:
   MsgBox strMsg
   Resume exitHandler

End Sub

Function DoesPathExist _
  (myPath As String) As Boolean
  Dim TestStr As String
  If Right(myPath, 1) <> "\" Then
      myPath = myPath & "\"
  End If
  TestStr = ""
  On Error Resume Next
  TestStr = Dir(myPath & "nul")
  On Error GoTo 0

  DoesPathExist = CBool(TestStr <> "")

End Function

Sub GetFolderFilesPDF()
Dim rngPath As Range
Dim PathStart As String
On Error Resume Next

Set rngPath = wksSet.Range("rngPath")
PathStart = ActiveWorkbook.Path
  
With Application.FileDialog _
 (msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
   .AllowMultiSelect = False
   .InitialFileName = PathStart
   .Show
    
   If .SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
       rngPath.Value = _
         .SelectedItems(1)
   End If
    
End With
  
End Sub

It was supposed to send test messages and it always did in Windows 11.  Now, I get a message that says "Outlook is not open."

Consider editing the post. Replace everything in Sub SendEmailWithPDF(bTest As Boolean) with two lines Dim OutApp As Object and Set OutApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application"). With Outlook open, what is the error?

What is "Windows 11 Outlook"? Do you mean the new web-based Outlook client (Monarch) rather than the desktop version of Outlook?

Sorry.  It just hasn't worked since I upgraded to Windows11.

@VickiMorrow your comment does not address either of the two requests for clarification

Sorry. I figured it out.  Apparently the "new look" Outlook is not a direct replacement for the old Outlook.  The new one does not support VBA.  So, my checks to see whether or not Outlook was open did not work.  I changed Outlook to go back to the "old look" and my macro worked.
